# When using select2 (v 4.0) on a jquery UI dialog, how can I get allowClear option to work when using a remote datasource?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-select2

I am using [select2 dropdown](https://select2.github.io/) and just upgraded to version 4.  The one feature that seems broken (or i am doing something wrong) is the allowClear option **when you have a remote data source AND the select2 is sitting on a jquery UI dialog**

It works fine if you data source is local (no ajax) or if there is no jquery UI dialog involved but when I try with a remote data source on a jquery UI dialog I see issues.

What is interesting is that when seetting allowClear = true, the "X" **DOES** shows up on the right side of the dropdown box after I search and choose an item, but when i click it, all of the select2 code runs but the previous selected value doesn't get removed.   I have debugged the select2.js code and all of the code that seems like it should be fired (handleClear, etc) does seem to be firing properly.

When testing on a local example, I see that this line of code is what actually removes the value:

```
 this.$element.val(this.placeholder.id).trigger('change');
```

bug when I debug the same code on a remote data source, nothing seems to change at all when that line of code fires.

From googling, the only related issue I see if if you don't specify a placeholder text ([example question here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1785)) but in my case, (as per below) I do specify this

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

and here is my code below that is setting up this select2 dropdown:

asp.net-MVC View:

```
 <% = Html.DropDownList("MyDropdownId", Model.DropdownItems, new {@id = "MyDropdown"}) %><br/><br/>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
$("#MyDropdown").select2({
    theme: "classic",
    width: "280px",
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
        url: "/MyController/Search",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 300,
        data: function (params) {
            return { q: params.term };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            return { results: data };
        },
        cache: false
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    placeholder: "Search",
    templateResult: streamFormatResult,
    templateSelection: streamSelectionResult
});
```

Has anyone else faced this issue or can see why clicking on the "X" in a select2 dropdown with remote data source wouldn't clear out the previously selected choice?

### Update

Given Kevin's answer below, the issue seems to be isolated to the fact that my select2 dropdown is on a jquery UI dialog (as if I try it on a regular page it does work as expected)

the only other code that I had to add (to get select2 working on a jquery UI dialog) was this code:

```
if ($.ui && $.ui.dialog && $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction) {
    var ui_dialog_interaction = $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._allowInteraction = function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.select2-dropdown').length) return true;
        return ui_dialog_interaction.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Without the code above the select2 input is not editable.  I am not sure if this is causing the issue to not clearing out the previous selected value when I click on the "X".

Comment: What's the HTML for `#MyDropdown`?

Comment: You're right, I grabbed the wrong question. Still, the HTML that you're using is important with this question, as that affects how the placeholder works.

Comment: I added the HTML (well the HTMLhelper) that I am using in my view

Comment: Did you try initializing Select2 *after* opening the dialog? It would help if you provided jQuery UI code & HTML

Answer (score 4):

When using a placeholder with a single select, **you must always provide an `<option></option>` for it**, even if you are using a remote data source. This is because Select2 needs a value to set the select to (usually a blank string), and the only way it can do that is with a placeholder option.

The easy solution if you have access to the HTML is to add a blank `<option>` inside the `<select>`.

```
<select>
  <option></option>
</option>
```

You can even add some helpful text to it that will be displayed to users, the `value` just has to be a blank string

```
<select>
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
</select>
```

Now, some frameworks will automatically generate the `<select>` for you. Luckily, most of these provide a way to define the "blank" or "placeholder" option for you. And if for some reason the framework doesn't, you can usually add a new option to the list of options you are telling the framework to render.

For ASP.NET MVC, you need can control the placeholder option by passing in a [another argument to `Html.DropDownList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String,System.Object%29).

```
<% = Html.DropDownList("MyDropdownId", Model.DropdownItems, "Select an option", new {@id = "MyDropdown"}) %>
```

And this should generate a blank placeholder at the top of the list of options.

Now, some frameworks will require that the placeholder option has a `value` other than a blank string. Select2 supports setting a custom placeholder `value` by passing in a data object instead of a string for the `placeholder`.

So for HTML that looks like

```
<select>
  <option value="-1">Select an option</option>
</select>
```

You would initialize Select2 using the following code for the `placeholder`

```
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: {
    id: '-1',
    text: 'Custom placeholder text'
  }
});
```

Here's an example of a remote data source (mocked, in this case) working with `placeholder` and `allowClear`. Keep in mind that you won't need to set `ajax.transport`, that's only needed because we aren't actually making a remote request.

```js
$('.js-states').select2({
  placeholder: {
    id: "-1",
    text: "Select a state..."
  },
  allowClear: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "/MyController/Search",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 300,
    data: function (params) {
      return { q: params.term };
    },
    processResults: function (data, params) {
      return { results: data };
    },
    cache: false,
    transport: function (params, success, failure) {
      var term = params.data.q || "";
      
      // mock response
      var response = [
        {
          id: "AK",
          text: "Alaska"
        },
        {
          id: "AL",
          text: "Alabama"
        },
        {
          id: "AZ",
          text: "Arizona"
        },
        {
          id: term || "nothing",
          text: term || ""
        }
      ];
      
      success(response);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select class="js-states" style="width: 50%">
  <option value="-1">Select a state</option>
</select>
```

Comment: do you have an example of this working as I have made a change to have exactly what you have and I still don't see anything different (clicking X still doesn't clear out the value).  One interesting note is that it seems like even if you add <option value="-1">Select an option</option>, this gets removed by select2 once you initialize

Comment: Are you still seeing no change when the value is set to `-1` and the `change` event is triggered? What is showing up with `$('select').val()`?

Comment: Yup. Select.val show the value that I am trying to remove

Comment: You mentioned that the option is being removed. Do you mean from the markup or from the results? Select2 shouldn't be removing anything on its own, so I'm not sure why it'd disappear from the markup.

Comment: yes, when I look at the source after the select2 is initialized, it removes the item from the original select . . have you ever seen what i am asking for work or have any example code as that would be quite helpful?

Comment: I just added an example with a mock AJAX request that demonstrates the expected HTML and `allowClear` working.

Comment: thanks that was very helpful as i used your exact code and still had the issue which made me think what else could be different.  I have isolated the issue to the fact that my select2 is on a jquery UI dialog.  I have updated the question title and details and to be more specific about this dialog use case.  I am still stuck on what to do to fix but at least now the problem is more isolated use case.  Do you have any ideas / suggestions? (I have upvoted your answer as it helped figure this out)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with jQuery UI Dialog [in a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fufatobimo/1/edit?html,js,output), maybe there's something else at play here? Or maybe I'm not replicating it properly.

Comment: [Let's continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88278/room-for-debugging-the-issue-in-question-32210811)